# Combining php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays in PHP (okay they are a bit bigger but the idea is what counts).

```
$array1 = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b');
$array2 = array(3 => 'c', 4 => 'd');
```

Essentially I want to combine the two arrays as if it were something like this

```
$array3 = array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b', 3 => 'c', 4 => 'd');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use

```
$array3 = $array1 + $array2;
```

See [Array Operators](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

By the way: [array_merge()](http://de3.php.net/array_merge) does something different with the arrays given in the example:

```
$a1=array(1 => 'a', 2 => 'b');
$a2=array(3 => 'c', 4 => 'd');
print_r($a1+$a2);
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => b
    [3] => c
    [4] => d
)
print_r(array_merge($a1, $a2));
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => d
)
```

Note the different indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can check array_combine function.

Answer (score -2):

array_merge only keeps STRING keys.
You have to wrote your function for doing this