# PHP combine two array

Tags: php

i have one array such as any `$_POST` without key,after clear html tags i want to merge and combine with other array.for example

**PHP**

```
$farray= array($a , $b , $c);
```

i want to merge with below array:

**PHP**

```
$filter=array('id'=>$farray[0], 
              'description'=>$farray[1], 
              'portal'=>$farray[2]);
```

those array are sample like my code, how to merge this arrays, i dont want to use array cell

Comment: Here's a similar question that has already been andswered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218174/combining-php-arrays?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

```
 $filter = array_combine(array("id","description", "portal"), $farray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're wanting, but there's `array_merge`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
$a1=array("a"=>"Horse","b"=>"Dog");
$a2=array("c"=>"Cow","d"=>"Cat");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

output will be Array ( [a] => Horse [b] => Dog [c] => Cow [d]=>Cat)